# The system is running in low graphics mode after Photorec filled up the HDD

Tags: graphics, data-recovery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to fix “The system is running in low-graphics mode” error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error)

Yesterday I installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my machine, since I had some previous problems. I had to recover files through Photorec. My hard-drive is full and I couldn't even finish the recovery process.

When I powered it up again, an error came up

> The system is running in low-graphics mode

I donˈt know if it has anything to do with the recovery process, or the that hard drive got full.  I need to delete those recup_dir folders, but also I need to finish recovering and get through the error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the Photorec thing, but have you tried to make system repairs by means of the Recovery GRUB menu...? If you don't see the GRUB menu, try hitting *Esc* while your PC is booting in order to display it...

Comment: ..but I stil donˈt see the GRUB menu :/

Answer (score 0):

If you use Nvidia:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo nvidia-xconfig
```

If this doesn't work try to change your download server in order to re-download all updates (Administration -> Update Manager -> Ubuntu Software -> Download from)

If you use Tor repository disable it (I don't know if this have to do with the problem but I did before solving it).

If you don't use Nvidia edit /etc/X11/xorg.conf as root instead of typing "sudo nvidia-xconfig".

Comment: Thanks, but it didnˈt work..something has happened, but Iˈm again stuck there..for sudo nvidia-xconfig it answered command not found..so I tried also that etc..and- Error: no write permission for file "etc/X11/xorg.conf"...what's wrong?

Comment: did you install nvidia drivers?
apt-get install nvidia-common nvidia-settings nvidia-current

Comment: It says I don't have enough space..